# Is it possible to alias an import?

Tags: swift, swift3

In c# when pulling in a library that has a lot of name collisions with existing code, there's a way to alias the import so you don't need to fully clarify the namespace for each use.  eg:

```
using MyCompany.MyLibrary.Model as MMM
```

then you could do

```
MMM.MyObject
```

instead of

```
MyCompany.MyLibrary.Model.MyObject
```

With the recent update to swift 3.0, I've found some of my model objects are now colliding with the `Foundation` types, and I've been forced to prefix things that used to have an `NS` prefix in the class name with `Foundation.classname`.  It would be great if I could type alias the import of my model library much like the c# example given above.  Is this possible in swift 3.0?  If not is there another strategy to avoid name collisions that would result in having to write the framework name in front of each type?  I'm considering going back to prefixing my class names like we did in obj-c, but I'm trying to explore my options before I do that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update 2021** for `Swift 5`;
**No**, but you can import all and alias (in separate file), read below for more details.

**Generally**

You can import a particular entity as well as the entire module:

```
import struct­ SomeModule.SomeStruct
import class­ SomeModule.SomeClass
import func SomeModule.someFunc
```

See the full list of "importable" entity types [in the `import-kind` rule of Swift grammar](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/import-kind).

Then you can create a `typealias`:

```
typealias SMSomeStruct = SomeModule.SomeStruct
```

And, as of Swift 3, there is no `import` declaration combined with aliasing.

**Considering the Collisions with `Foundation` Entities**

Say, you have a class `SomeModule.NumberFormatter`.

It is enough to create two `typealias`es in a separate Swift file (in an importing project) to prevent collisions:

```
import Foundation
import SomeModule

typealias NumberFormatter = Foundation.NumberFormatter
typealias SMNumberFormatter = SomeModule.NumberFormatter
```

Comment: as of Swift 3? I believe this feature was in Swift since the beginning.

Comment: I suppose you're right. The main reason to write "as of Swift 3" was that I cannot be sure whether it will be true in Swift 4+. I removed the first "as of Swift 3", because it's nearly impossible that Apple will remove the feature from the language.

Answer (score 1):

It's not even with `Swift 5` possible to directly alias an import-statement!?

But fortunately, I could workaround it with something like:

```swift
import typealias MyModule.MyInnerClass
```

I mean, if we are the module's developer, simply move the alias into the module, like:

```swift
public typealias MyInnerClass = MyClass.MyInnerClass

public class MyClass {
    public class MyInnerClass {
        // Some cool logic here...
    }
}
```